# Discrepancy in the size of compressed file

Tags: command-line, tar, compression

I was trying to compress a folder into .tar format.

The folder size is around 76 MB.

Suppose I want to compress the folder `myfolder` to `my-compressed-folder` (in *tar* format)

I tried 2 approaches:

1) In the terminal, I executed:

```
tar -cjvf my-compressed-folder myfolder
```

The size of .tar by this method is 23 MB

2) On using the in-built `Compress` after right clicking on `myfolder` & choosing the *.tar.xz*, the size of .tar is around 17 MB.

I have 2 doubts:

1) How is there so much size difference in the 2 compressed files in same (.tar) format?

2) Is there any Linux command by which I can create compressed .tar files with the compression ratio same as the in-built `Compress` feature of Ubuntu?

My system details are as follows:

```
Ubuntu Desktop
Version 18.04.4 LTS (64-bit)
```

Comment: Doesn't the `-j` option of `tar` produce a bzip2 compressed file? if you want an apples to apples comparison to the xz file, you should use `-J` I think?

Comment: @K7AAY I have added the Ubuntu system details

Comment: @steeldriver would try that now & update you shortly

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! ```tar -cJvf``` worked :) How may I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: I have added a brief answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man tar`:

> ```
>    -j, --bzip2
>           Filter the archive through bzip2(1).
>
>    -J, --xz
>           Filter the archive through xz(1).
> ```

so your command `tar -cjvf my-compressed-folder myfolder` created a bzip2-compressed archive rather than an xz-compressed archive.

For an apples-to-apples comparison with the `tar.xz` file that you created from the file manager, you should use `tar -cJvf my-compressed-folder myfolder`.

Comment: Thanks once again! I thought they both (j and J) would work same like other options in many other Linux commands, but I was wrong